# How to display invoice details in Details View from invoice header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have two tables:  invoice_header (PK: org_number, supplier_number, invoice_number) and invoice_line (PK:  org_number, supplier_number, invoice_number, seq).
My Index view displays records from invoice_header.  I am trying to get the Details view to display the corresponding records from the invoice_line table.

I'm receiving the error:  "The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
Parameter name: keyValues"

The error is here:
[image: Controller]

And here is the relevant section from the Index view:
[image: Index view]

I suspect I need to have something for the "seq" column which is part of the composite PK on invoice_line.  I want to see all records that match on org_number, supplier_number and invoice_number, regardless of seq.

Comment: What is db?  Entity Framework, Linq-2-Sql, etc...

Comment: i'm new to EF, so please bear with me if I'm not answering your question correctly.  dbEntities is a database (in Teradata), and there are two tables (invoice_header and invoice_line): private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework, which I suspect you are, then Find is the wrong method. Find is for searching by primary keys and that would require you to feed in the values of the composite key. In this case I believe the method you want is Where. That will allow you to search via values instead of finding by the key.

Keep in mind that Where will not hit the PK index and can have performance issues. You'll want to do some testing. You can check out the link below to see a comparison of query types for EF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  I'm working through how to change my code over to 'where' and will respond once I've confirmed the solution.